# use tempus dominus datetimepicker with CLASS instead of ID and for multiple instances

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

tempus dominus  datetimepicker is working with ID  like

```
input#datetimepicker4.form-control.datetimepicker-input data-target="#datetimepicker4" data-toggle="datetimepicker" type="text"


$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L'
});
```

and with CLASS like

```
input.datetimepicker.form-control.datetimepicker-input data-target=".datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker" type="text"

$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L'
    });
```

But its working for only one instance, may be due to using data-target as well

Actually, there are multiple date fields on single form with dynamic IDs so can't use like this.

Is there a way to use it with CLASS and for multiple instances?

Comment: Hi did you solve your issue?, are you able to use class in datetimepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it doesn't work with class but you could try initializing individual instances in a loop like:

```
$('.datetimepicker').each(function(){
  $(this).datetimepicker({
      format: 'L'
  });
})
```

Note you have a different class in the commented out selector which is `datetimepicker-input`. Might be using wrong class altoghether

Comment: thanks but still not working as seems it uses data target as well like
input.datetimepicker.form-control.datetimepicker-input data-target=".datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker" type="text"

Comment: Not familiar with that plugin to be honest. Might need to check docs for it. Also, are you loading any of this using ajax? Any errors in browser console?

Comment: I updated my question, no error in browser console, there is ajax call but loading js after js as well.